# How to add a condition to JSON list Dictionary based on indexing in python

Tags: python, json

My Json example

```
[ {'key' : 1, 'value' : 'one' } , {'key' : 2, 'value' : 'two' } , {'key' : 3, 'value' : 'three' } , {'key' : 4, 'value' : 'four' }]
```

i have a flag isVisible which i am setting it to False initially,

```
isVisible = False
```

I want to make my Flag to True only at the last index in each element inside a list.

Desired Output (How Flag should change it's value):

```
[{'key' : 1, 'value' : 'one' },
isVisible = True

{'key' : 2, 'value' : 'two' },
isVisible = True

{'key' : 3, 'value' : 'three' },
isVisible = True

{'key' : 4, 'value' : 'four' },
isVisible = True
]
```

please correct me or edit if i'm missing something as i'm still learning.

Comment: do you want that invisible value inside object or as a separate value in main array?

Comment: i want to achieve something like ---> if (atRequiredIndex) : isVisible = True , not inside the JSON,i've just illustrated how the output is required JSON can't be modified.

Comment: if you are iterating in that array you  can do something like the answer i posted

Comment: More details? not clear enough

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed , to be simply put i want to add some condition after looping each element (each element here is one dictionary) inside list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,element in enumerate(arr):
    if (i==len(arr)-1):
        print("last element" )
    else:
        print("Not last element" )
```

you can get index like this and check if it is last element or not!

Comment: With this approach i will always get my flag condition True , i want it to be true only at the position i showed above

Comment: just replace print("last element" ) with the task you want to do at last index and  print("Not last element" ) with the task you want to do for other indexes

Comment: Yes ofcourse that's how i tried, i think I'm lacking in explaining the question clearly i will edit this Question to make it more clear, thanks for your effort